# Asp.Net HtmlHelper with a Generic only work inside a @Razor statement

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor

I would like to understand why the following code does not work while the second work:

```
@Html.Test<ContestListItemViewModel>() //Does not work

@{
    var x = Html.Test<ContestListItemViewModel>();//Work
            @Html.Raw(x);//Work
}
```

The code of this Test helper is very simple:

```
    public static MvcHtmlString Test<TEntityType>(this HtmlHelper htmlHelper)
    {
        return new MvcHtmlString("<p>Test</P>");
    }
```

The error is during the execution:

> An exception of type 'System.Web.HttpCompileException' occurred in
>   System.Web.dll but was not handled in user code
>   Compiler Error Message: CS1502: The best overloaded method match for
>   'System.Web.WebPages.WebPageExecutingBase.Write(System.Web.WebPages.HelperResult)'
>   has some invalid arguments

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Razor parser is confused. It doesn't know if that is HTML or C#.

Try:

```
@(Html.Test<ContestListItemViewModel>())
```

In the second example the statement is wrapped in a Razor code block, so it knows for sure.

Wrapping in parentheses can often solve code confusion problems like this.

Comment: Thank you Rowan, your solution worked. It is weird because this is not required if I create a Html Helper that is not generic. Wrapping with parentheses did the job.

Comment: The key is `<ContestListItemViewModel>`. It thinks it's HTML.